# how to initialize function arguments that are classes with default value

Tags: c++, gcc, reference, default-value

I'm working on Linux gcc environment and I need to initilize function arguments that are classes with default values.
When I do that with temporary instance of the class it makes an error like this: "default argument for [function argument] has type [class name].
for example:

```
void foo(std::wstring& str = std::wstring())
```

error: default argument for 'std::wstring& str' has type 'std::wstring'
P.S. this code is compiled without any error or warning with VC++.

How can I initilize the default value?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? To me, it looks meaningless what you are doing..

Comment: @Simone -this is probably a trial to get both adventages of default values and sending by reference.

Comment: binding to non-const references is not standard compliant, but VC++ allows it as an extension AFAIK.

Comment: Found this article on lvalues and rvalues and const helpful: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/understanding-meaning-lvalues-and-rvalues-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is supposed to not compile. You are trying to bind an rvalue to a non-const reference. Say `std::wstring const & str` and it should work.

Answer (score 10):

You could just create a function overload:

```
void foo() {
    std::wstring str;
    foo(str);
}
```

but I really miss the point.

EDIT:
I mean, that function's purpose is almost certainly to modify an input string. If you provide an empty input string that you can't access later, why bother?

Comment: Function's purpose can be also get the input string without modifying it at all. The passing by reference can be also for preventing the copy constructor from being called.

Comment: there are many situations where it could be useful, say for example that this isn't a string, but a buffer, or that some data (like detailed logs) is put there by the method but you only care about the result. Your solution gently solves the issue with standard compliant code nonetheless :)

Comment: @rursw1 yes, but - in such cases - if you don't pass a **const** reference I think the function's interface is somehow wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot bind non-const references to rvalues. Passing by value would work:

```
void foo(std::wstring str = std::wstring())
```

Or passing by reference-to-const:

```
void foo(const std::wstring& str = std::wstring())
```

Comment: I don't really understand your last sentence. Even if the compiler doesn't optimize out the temporary and the copy how expensive is copying an empty string really going to be? And if the temporary is elided, what's left to move?

Comment: @Charles: What if a user *does* supply a string as an argument? Then it must be copied in C++03.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to the use of the default argument in your comment. In any case, if the user supplies a string that is a temporary in many cases it can be elided in C++03. A copy doesn't always have to happen.

Comment: @Charles: Right, let me rephrase that: what if the argument is an lvalue of type wstring? :)

Comment: Then it as to be copied in either C++03 or C++0x. You can only move from rvalues (xvalues or prvalues). [I'm not quite sure where this inquisition is heading?]

Comment: @Charles: Right... I guess I should probably just remove the last sentence :)