# error: default argument for parameter of type ‘bar<int>&’ has type ‘bar<int>’

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am getting the above mentioned error while compiling , how can I rectify it.
Please help me sort this out

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class bar
{
 public:
 bar(){cout << "bar" <<"\n";}
};

template <typename T, typename ctor = bar<T>>
class foo
{
 T i;
public:
 explicit foo(ctor& c = ctor());
private:
 ctor mctor;


};

template <typename T, typename ctor>
foo<T,ctor>::foo(ctor& c):mctor(c)
{
 cout << "foo" <<"\n";
}

int main()
{
 foo<int> f;
 return 0;
}
```

compile: g++ -std=c++11 ctor_call.cpp

Comment: Interesting, which compiler and version do you use? I get "error: could not convert ‘bar<int>()’ from ‘bar<int>’ to ‘bar<int>&’" and "error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bar<int>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘bar<int>’" with GCC 4.9.2. The latter error actually explains the cause pretty well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're giving a default argument for a parameter that is supposed to be passed by reference in this line:

```
explicit foo(ctor& c = ctor());
```

Here, `ctor&` is a reference to an object of type `ctor`.  So that object needs to exist for as long as you'll have a reference to it.  But the default argument sets it equal to a temporary object that will be [destroyed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) soon.  And since temporary objects are not standardized, it could be destroyed before the constructor begins, so you'd be left with a reference to nothing.  There's a nice explanation of all this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14612972/1194883).

Your case is just a little more complicated by the templates, so let's be a little more specific.  The default `ctor()` is a call to the constructor of the object you're taking a reference to.  In your case, the class is `foo<int>`, so the template looks like

```
template <int, typename ctor = bar<int>>
class foo
```

Here, the template is getting a second argument, but it's the default argument, so you get `ctor = bar<int>`.  This is equivalent to using `foo<int, bar<int>>`.  Now, in your function statement, `ctor()` is really just the same as `bar<int>()` -- it's a call to the constructor.

## A few possible solutions

1) Don't pass a default:

```
explicit foo(ctor& c);
```

2) Don't pass by reference:

```
explicit foo(ctor c = ctor());
```

3) Pass by *const* reference:

```
explicit foo(const ctor& c = ctor());
```

This works a little magic, because the `const` makes the compiler [keep the temporary object around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14612972/1194883) until the const reference is destroyed, which comes at the end of the `foo` constructor call.

4) Use something that exists outside of the `foo` object, such as a static or global object.  (Though you should be wary of static, and we basically all hate globals...):

```
explicit foo(ctor& c = some_ctor_object_that_exists_already);
```

Comment: In your "don't pass by reference"... there's a reference. Copy/Paste error?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. can you please give some source to understand how template ctor is used as function/operator() ctor() in line explicit foo(ctor& c = ctor());

Comment: @knils Sorry, I don't really understand your comment.  I've added to my answer to be more clear, but if that's not enough, please explain the comment a little more.

Comment: Thanks Mike! for such lucid explanation.when I pass it by reference I had to use const as reference had to point to some memory location and as object goes out of scope momentarily or pass by value. What is the  points/stages where bar object goes out of scope and comes back into it. courtesy "But the default argument sets it equal to an object that will be destroyed momentarily because of scope."

Comment: Ah, my North American English may have led you astray.  By destroyed "momentarily" I mean "soon", rather than "temporarily, and then it will be undestroyed".  For the const reference version, the object constructed with `ctor()` will exist [as long as the const reference exists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14612972/1194883), which is until the constructor finishes.

Comment: What does _"temporary objects are not standardized"_ mean?

Comment: I guess it's not important to the argument, but...  As I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong), the C++ standards don't demand that a temporary object in this guise be destroyed on any particular schedule.  I guess this is pretty squishy anyway, since `ctor& c = ctor()` is something that can't happen; I just wanted to give some sort of logic for why it shouldn't.